# How do I convert from an extracted value back to the original?

Tags: c#

I am using the following method to create a hexadecimal key, which in this instance returned "41AE-1456D".  Is there a way to take the key "41AE-1456D" and get back to the original Guid Value?

```
var g = "b4a76e9d-f9d6-48f1-a11c-d08a2c8cfcc2"+ "0001";
var b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(g);
var s = BitConverter.ToUInt32(b, 8).ToString();
var s11 = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(0, l1)).ToString("X");
var s12 = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(l2)).ToString("X");
var ss = string.Format("{0}-{1}", s11, s12);
```

I get stuck at the the `ToUint32` statement. I can't seem to figure a way to get the original bytes.

Comment: the original guid is 16 byte = 128 bit long, the digest is 36 bit. this is not a reversible operation. guids do not contain redundant information (assuming this is a real GUID, a globally unique identifier.)

Comment: Can you isolate the case?  Do you want to revert from BitConverter.ToUInt32(b, 8) ?

Comment: You can't get back the original bytes, because most of them are gone. GUID is a 128-bit number, while you seem to extract only 32 bits from the middle. The other 96 bits are no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

No, because there is too little information in that 36 bit digest to reconstruct the 128 bit of the original (ignoring the fact that you seem to include the dashes, and starting at offset 8 which is the first dash, so the LSB of `s` will be constant 0x2D).

Given that you actually use only 32 bits (one `uint`), no matter what values you chose for `l1` and `l2`, 96 bits are just missing.

What you can do, is find 2<sup>116</sup> GUIDs that, when digested using your code, will return the same digest. Somewhat like how the MD5 vulnerability works.